# Drawing spots on black image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wrote a sample code to draw white spots on a black image. I was able to draw  single spot at a time. I would like to give a set of points as input and draw white image spots on the black image. Can anyone suggest me on how to proceed?

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import time
class ImageHandler(object):
"""
with the aspect of no distortion and looking from the same view
"""

    reso_width = 0
    reso_height = 0
    radius = 10
    def __init__(self,width,height,spotlight_radius= 10):
        self.reso_width = width
        self.reso_height = height
        self.radius = spotlight_radius

    def get_image_spotlight(self,set_points): #function for drawing spot light
        image,draw = self.get_black_image()
        for (x,y) in set_points:
            draw.ellipse((x-self.radius,y-self.radius,x+self.radius,y+self.radius),fill = 'white')
        image.show("titel")
        return image

    def get_black_image(self):   #function for drawing black image
        image = Image.new('RGBA',(self.reso_width,self.reso_height),"black")#(ImageHandler.reso_width,ImageHandler.reso_height),"black")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw((image))
        return image,draw


hi = ImageHandler(1000,1000)
a = []
hi.get_image_spotlight((a))
for i in range(0,100):
    a = [(500,500)]
    hi.get_image_spotlight((a))
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: You could use matlabplot to achieve what you are looking for [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the `ImageHandler` class looks like it does what you require. Presently it is being passed a list containing a single point. This same point is being drawn on the black image once, so you'll only ever see one spot, and it will always be in the same position.

Instead pass a list containing more than one point to `get_image_spotlight()`. You could generate a random list of points and then draw them:

```
from random import randrange

spot_count = 10
points = [(randrange(1000), randrange(1000)) for _ in range(spot_count)]
img = hi.get_image_spotlight(points)
```

This will create an image with 10 white spots on a black background. Change `spot_count` for more or fewer spots.